# Is it possible to completely disable Grub timeout?

Tags: 12.04, grub2, burg, timeout

I am setting up a dual boot install for my wife's computer. I would like to disable the timeout for selecting OS that defaults to Ubuntu so the computer wont boot without making a selection. (IE. `GRUB_TIMEOUT=INFINITE`) Is it just a simple case of leaving it blank or `#out` the line in `/etc/default/grub` ? I want it so my wife can choose OS easily on her newly Dual booting PC.

I would also like to know if updating Burg after this would keep the change - as the big graphics of the OS's are a little more noob friendly.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Edit `/etc/default/grub` (with root privileges), change `GRUB_TIMEOUT` value from `10` to `-1`, save the file and then run `sudo update-grub`. Reboot and now you have infinite time to choose the OS.

While this works in GRUB, it doesn't work with BURG, and you'll have to change `GRUB_TIMEOUT` value to some large number like `120` seconds to wait before booting into any OS and run `sudo update-burg` to reflect the changes. Also note that this change must be made to file `/etc/default/burg` as BURG doesn't consider options set in `/etc/default/grub`

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you very much. I set it to 600 seconds with Burg and it's awesome.

Comment: Which versions of Ubuntu does this apply to?

Answer (score 7):

**Setting timeout to -1 will make GRUB wait infinitely**.

By that I mean that you will be required to manually select an entry and hit Enter before launching any OS.

Answer (score 2):

When running `update-grub` a warning says that setting grubtimeout to a non zero number is no longer supported. No matter what I changed the grub timeout value to timeout stayed at 10. If you are having this problem the workaround is editing the `grub.cfg` file located in `/boot/grub`. Near the end the script says `IF TIMEOUT = 0 then timeout= 10`. Change `10` to `-1`. No more countdown.

1. `gksu gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg`
2. Find the part of the script around the end that says `IF TIMEOUT = 0 then timeout= 10`. Change `10` to `-1`.

*This is a workaround it will be reverted if `update-grub` is ever run. Not permanent unless `update-grub` is not manually run.*

(Works on 14.04.)

Answer (score 1):

1. Edit `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` file:

   ```sh
   sudo gedit /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober
   ```
2. Find

   ```sh
   if [ "\${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
     set timeout=10
   fi
   ```

   and replace `set timeout=10` with `set timeout=0`
3. Save and update grub config:

   ```sh
   sudo update-grub
   ```

It worked for me, on Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: It is not recommended to edit the generated script. Use the `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` or the `update-grub` script after editing the `/etc/default/grub` configuration file. Just add `GRUB_TIMEOUT=-1` to it.

Comment: @BalázsBörcsök, files stored in the `/etc/grub.d/` directory are not generated files. On the contrary, these are source scripts used to generate `/boor/grub/grub.cfg`. You can read the contents of `/etc/grub.d/README`. The problem there is that script called `30_os-prober` is written in such a way that it effectively forces GRUB timeout of 10 seconds if another OS is found. See the second code excerpt from Maxim Mazurok - the `timeout` variable is set in global scope of the grub.cfg script AFTER setting the timeout variable globally to value defined with `GRUB_TIMEOUT` in `/etc/default/grub`.