# Grub wait time 10 seconds after editing to "0" in /etc/default/grub?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 15.04

Using all of the solutions described on this site, setting the Grub menu wait time to zero does not work.

I did the following:

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.old    
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Uncommented this line, per instruction.

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
```

Set this line, per instruction.

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT="0"
```

**/etc/default/grub** now looks like this:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg. 
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash profile"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Having edited the **/etc/default/grub** file -->

```
sudo update-grub
```

After restarting, Grub wait-time is still set to 10 seconds.

I was able to get the **wait time to 1 second** with just one simple change.  Edited these two lines in **/etc/default/grub**

```
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"

GRUB_TIMEOUT="1"
```

Commented the first back to the default value, and set GRUB_TIMEOUT to "1".

After,

```
sudo update-grub
```

**This solution works, but my question is:**

**Where is the trap that resets the TIMEOUT value to 10 seconds when GRUB-TIMEOUT is set to "0".**

Maybe one of the "IF" tests in **grub.cfg**??

Comment: May be this will help you http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119865/grub-doesnt-have-the-timeout-anymore

Comment: @Qasim I had read that, but there is no explanation as to why Grub defaults to 10 seconds when values are set to "0" and yet if you set 'GRUB-TIMEOUT="1"' Grub functions exactly like it should, boot sequence starts in 1 second.

Comment: Just for troubleshooting purposes, does it still do this if you comment out the GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT and GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET lines and only have the GRUB_TIMEOUT line set to 0?

Comment: @thomasrutter yes, I have tried this in every possible combination using the zero value.  There is something that does not allow a 0 value if you are dual booting OS's.  There are a couple of accepted answers on this site stating that it will work, but that simply is not the case with Grub2 and 15.04.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to completely disable Grub timeout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136070/is-it-possible-to-completely-disable-grub-timeout)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1273764). The problem is in the file `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`.

As presented [here](https://gist.github.com/LeahCim/9332432), a workaround is to add the files `/etc/grub.d/25_pre-os-prober` and `/etc/grub.d/35_post-os-prober`.

The two files must also be marked as executable to work.

After adding this two files, your modifications to the variable `GRUB_TIMEOUT` in `/etc/default/grub` should work as expected.

If you are *not* dual booting, another workaround is to uninstall `os-prober`.

### 25_pre-os-prober:

```
#! /bin/sh
# file: /etc/grub.d/25_pre-os-prober
set -e

# Save the $timeout and $timeout_style values set by /etc/grub.d/00_header
# before /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober messes them up.

cat << EOF
set timeout_bak=\${timeout}
set timeout_style_bak=\${timeout_style}
EOF
```

### 35_post-os-prober

```
#! /bin/sh
# file: /etc/grub.d/35_post-os-prober
set -e

# Reset $timeout and $timeout_style to their original values
# set by /etc/grub.d/00_header before /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober messed them up.

cat << EOF
set timeout=\${timeout_bak}
set timeout_style=\${timeout_style_bak}
EOF
```

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: I've edited `30_os-prober` on Ubuntu 19.10 and it worked like a charm, here are the exact steps: https://askubuntu.com/a/1189737/518931

Answer (score 6):

There is an override in grub for when the timeout is 0 seconds to replace it with 10 seconds. Rather than editing grub scripts as other answers recommend you can simply use:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0.0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="0.0"
```

This will work because the grub overrides will not find `"0"` to be equal to `"0.0"`.

Comment: This is so simple and it works.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the documentation at `info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'`, it is said that `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_*` is deprecated.

Could you try using instead in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
# rest of file unchanged
```

Run

```
sudo update-grub
```

and see if it works or not.

You could *double-check* in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` looking for **timeout** that the update has correctly been done.

Answer (score 0):

I've always been able to get a 0 second time, although a 1 second time isn't much more wasted time.  Try changing this line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash profile"
```

to this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
```

I don't see anything in this config file that seems out of whack, but you might try this if you're desperate to save 1 second during boot time.

Comment: I'm really not desperate at all, 1 second is totally acceptable.  What I am seeking is where is the trap which disallows the "0" wait time and resets to 10 seconds.  Wouldn't it be reasonable to expect a warning that the "0" value is not accepted, please reset to any non-zero number?

Comment: It would be reasonable to expect that, but it's also reasonable for the devs to expect users to not need to change it.  Is update-grub a binary file? or is it just a script?

Comment: you should be able to answer your Grub question here -> [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2]

Answer (score 0):

Editing `/etc/default/grub` is insufficient.

The following modifications are also required:

Disable grub timeout using one of these methods:

```
sudoedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

comment out these lines (by placing a `#` at the start of the lines)

```
#if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then  
#set timeout=10  
#fi
```

save the file and exit.

OR (better, as the above would need to be re-done each time the file is generated, which happens whenever `update-grub` is called):

```
sudoedit /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober
```

comment out these lines

```
#if [ "\${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
#set timeout=10
#fi
```

save, exit and then run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Your answer does not address what the OP asked.