# How to stop a dual boot system from Auto starting on xubuntu after hibernation?

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu, windows-10

I have Windows 10 dual booting with xubuntu using the grub boot loader. When using Windows, I have my laptop lid close action to hibernation. When I open it up the next day, xubuntu is Auto started on the screen. This is somewhat annoying. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either change the default OS to boot in grub, which sounds like what you want, or disable the autostart completetly.

To **change** the default OS to boot you can take a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/110738/931850).

If you want to **disable** the autostart completetly go [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/136077/931850)